# Only 1 intranet site is accessible when off the network

Tags: networking, website, iis

I have a few intranet sites hosted on IIS version 10 and windows server 2016. My PC is on a different network than the server, so in order to view these sites, I have to VPN onto its network. Everything works well.

However, there is one site in particular that I am able to access without needing to VPN to the server's network. As far as I know, the firewall rules, web.config's, application settings are the same for all sites.  What could be the cause of this? Where can I troubleshoot?

Answer (score 0):

Well Its hard to say because we don't know if the servers sitis in one subnet or in different subnets and if the firewall rules are set per ip or per subnet. I would do a simple test just do tracert to intranet website which you can not connect then do tracert to intranet website which you can connect check if the path is the same if yes then check where traffic stops. If this is intranet -> intranet connection it most likely do not going through firewall I would expect it passing router with ACLs.